# "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Guid?' to 'System.Guid'." - Nullable GUID

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, guid, nullable

In my database, in one of the table I have a GUID column with allow nulls. I have a method  with a Guid? parameter that inserts a new data row in the table. However when I say `myNewRow.myGuidColumn = myGuid` I get the following error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Guid?' to 'System.Guid'.
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The ADO.NET API has some problems when it comes to handling nullable value types (i.e. it simply doesn't work correctly). We've had no end of issues with it, and so have arrived at the conclusion that it's best to manually set the value to null, e.g.

```
myNewRow.myGuidColumn = myGuid == null ? (object)DBNull.Value : myGuid.Value
```

It's painful extra work that ADO.NET should handle, but it doesn't seem to do so reliably (even in 3.5 SP1). This at least works correctly.

We've also seen issues with passing nullable value types to SqlParameters where the generated SQL includes the keyword `DEFAULT` instead of `NULL` for the value so I'd recommend the same approach when building parameters.

Comment: Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.DBNull' and 'System.Guid'

Comment: You might consider using the null coalescing operator when retrieving a fallback value for a possible null object: "(object)myGuid ?? DBNull.Value"

Comment: @Emperor XLII - you can't do that because you want DBNull.Value when the value you have *is* null, not when it isn't.

Comment: This is telling me Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Guid?'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) -- but explicitly casting to Guid? doesn't work either.

Answer (score 10):

OK; how is myGuidColumn defined, and how is myGuid defined?

If myGuid is `Guid?` and myGuidColumn is `Guid`, then the error is correct: you will need to use `myGuid.Value`, or `(Guid)myGuid` to get the value (which will throw if it is null), or perhaps `myGuid.GetValueOrDefault()` to return the zero guid if null.

If myGuid is `Guid` and myGuidColumn is `Guid?`, then it should work.

If myGuidColumn is `object`, you probably need `DBNull.Value` instead of the regular null.

Of course, if the column is truly nullable, you might simply want to ensure that it is `Guid?` in the C# code ;-p

Answer (score 6):

same as Greg Beech's answer

```
myNewRow.myGuidColumn = (object)myGuid ?? DBNull.Value
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to cast `null` to a `nullable Guid`, this how it worked for me :

```
myRecord.myGuidCol = (myGuid == null) ? (Guid?)null : myGuid.Value
```

Answer (score 4):

Try System.Guid.Empty where you want it to be null

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid working with nullable GUIDs in your c# code (personally, I often find it cumbersome to work with nullable types) you could somewhere early assign [Guid.Empty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.empty.aspx) to the .NET data which is null in the db. That way, you don't have to bother with all the .HasValue stuff and just check if `myGuid != Guid.Empty` instead.

Answer (score 2):

or:

```
    internal static T CastTo<T>(object value)
    {
        return value != DBNull.Value ? (T)value : default(T);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a helper method:

```
public static class Ado {
    public static void SetParameterValue<T>( IDataParameter parameter, T? value ) where T : struct {
        if ( null == value ) { parameter.Value = DBNull.Value; }
        else { parameter.Value = value.Value; }
    }
    public static void SetParameterValue( IDataParameter parameter, string value ) {
        if ( null == value ) { parameter.Value = DBNull.Value; }
        else { parameter.Value = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are into extension methods...

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns nullable Guid (Guid?) value if not null or Guid.Empty, otherwise returns DBNull.Value
/// </summary>
public static object GetValueOrDBNull(this Guid? aGuid)
{
  return (!aGuid.IsNullOrEmpty()) ? (object)aGuid : DBNull.Value;
}

/// <summary>
/// Determines if a nullable Guid (Guid?) is null or Guid.Empty
/// </summary>
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this Guid? aGuid)
{
  return (!aGuid.HasValue || aGuid.Value == Guid.Empty);
}
```

Then you could say:
`myNewRow.myGuidColumn = myGuid.GetValueOrDBNull();`

NOTE: This will insert null when `myGuid == Guid.Empty`, you could easily tweak the method if you want to allow empty Guids in your column.

Answer (score 0):

```
Guid? _field = null;
if (myValue!="")//test if myValue has value
{
_field = Guid.Parse(myValue)
}
```